# How to use appRoleAssignment in Graph Api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to leverage the beta api for assigning azure users to applications.

I looked at the documentation and tried a variety of attempts in a C# console app using `HttpClient` and `WebClient` and couldn't succeed. I then went to the Microsoft graph explorer https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer . I couldn't get it to work.

I looked at the documentation
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/approleassignment_get

The document's actual documentation of the HTTP request which doesn't match the Example.  The Graph Explorer seems to hint that the example is correct, but through various attempts, I can only get a response of

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "Direct queries to this resource type are not supported.",
        ...
    }
}
```

My essential url is
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/appRoleAssignments/

The example says `{id}` but I have no idea what to put in. I put in several guids, user ids, object ids, resource ids, and none worked.

It isn't saying any access denied messages so I assume it has nothing to do with Scopes (all though the documentation is a little empty regarding that as well).

Ideally, I'd be able to see if for a given Guest Azure User has access to a particular App, then I'd be able to go and Update the assignment. I'll probably also need to delete the assignment as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Edit (2021-07-06): Use Microsoft Graph v1.0 for all of this.]

<strike>It looks like the Microsoft Graph API's beta endpoint doesn't currently allow you to list AppRoleAssignments.</strike>

<strike>[Edit (2018-10-11): The Microsoft Graph beta endpoint now supports the ability to list AppRoleAssignments, though you should still use Azure AD Graph for any production application, until it gets to v1.0.] Fortunately, the [Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog) *does* work for this (plus, it's not a beta endpoint, so it's more likely to be stable).</strike>

To list all app roles a user is assigned with Microsoft Graph:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/appRoleAssignments
```

To list all app roles a group is assigned:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/appRoleAssignments
```

To do the reverse, and list all users or groups assigned to an app:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{id}/appRoleAssignedTo
```

[Azure AD Graph is deprecated and all support for it will cease in June 2022.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/migrate-azure-ad-graph-planning-checklist) The equivalent requests were (in the same order as above):

```
https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/users/{id}/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6
https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/groups/{id}/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6
https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/servicePrincipals/{id}/appRoleAssignedTo?api-version=1.6
```

Comment: Thanks, this is looking like my only choice, I'm going to have to look deeper into this. The current documentation shows, go use the graph.microsoft.com api as that's newer, but it's looking like graph.windows.net might be the better option for me.

Comment: Yes, that may be worded a bit too strongly. We do recommend Microsoft Graph for anything that Microsoft Graph can already do, but as you see, the are still several functionalities only available in Azure AD Graph. It's normally fairly simple for your application to call both.

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret It's been over a year and 4 months since this post, is this still the case with Microsoft Graph? I'm getting the same results but it seems that the github pages have been somewhat updated since then.

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret I have just tried your third example to get all users and groups assigned to an app, I'm getting `appRolesAssignedTo does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present'

Comment: @SebastianG I just updated the post, with two corrections: 1) this _is_ now available in the Microsoft Graph (but only in beta), and 2) I had a typo in the last one--it's "appRoleAssignedTo", instead of "appRole**s**AssignedTo"

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret thanks, that works well for reading -- I can't believe how much I've struggled and didn't catch that small typo, crazy! Having some problems on the "PATCH/POST" side of things to add users to app roles but have posted a separate thread here. 

Thanks again.

Comment: Azure AD reference for role assignments (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#approleassignment-entity) did it for me. Getting the bearer token is tricky, though.

Comment: Can you advise, why none of above queries are returning actual role display name?
PrincipalDisplayName is the object who have the role, and I was expecting ResourceDisplayName to contain the role name, but it contains principal description instead

Comment: @donatasj87 In an app role assignment, the "principal" is the user, group or service principal to which the app role was assigned, and the "resource" is the resource service which has defined the app role. The `appRoleAssignment` entity in Microsoft Graph does not currently include the app role display name or claim value, only the app role ID.

Answer (score 2):

In the new Azure portal, under `"Enterprise applications" > (your app) > "Users and groups"`, you'll see the list of users who are assigned to the application, as well as the app role they are assigned to. After testing , you could do the equivalent thing using Microsoft Graph API request :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/d0790296-0a14-4ab1-8f6c-4e4d3eb03036/appRoleAssignments
```

Your could get the service principal under `"Enterprise applications" > (your app) >Properties>Object ID` .Here is sample of the response :
[image]

`id` is the role id , In your scenario ,you could check whether record exists when the `principalId` matches the object id of the specific user , and `principalType` is `user` .

Comment: your example above worked thanks.

(ids are based on your screenshot above)
My next focus is to add a new assignment, which I've failed to do.
I tried both 
/graph.microsoft.com/beta/appRoleAssignments/d0790296-0a14-4ab1-8f6c-4e4d3eb03036
and 
/graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/d0790296-0a14-4ab1-8f6c-4e4d3eb03036/appRoleAssignments

Comment: I did use the PATCH webmethod
my json payload included


    json["creationTimestamp"] = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    json["id"] = null; // tried with and without
    json["principalId"] = "563d3cd6-7538-4836-9d7c-1d321426444d";
    json["principalType"] = "User";
    json["resourceId"] = "d0790296-0a14-4ab1-8f6c-4e4d3eb03036";

I get bad_request

I'm going to eventually need to delete the appRoleAssignment is it going to be the created "id"
(i.e. "1jw9Vjh1Nkidf80yFCZETB5YC8Pu8F9PvEIS3h5jTRA")

Comment: According to document , microsoft graph api beta version doesn't provide create new assignment , and since that's beta version , you could use azure ad graph api instead.