# How to use Azure AD Graph API to create a new AppRoleAssignment

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to figure out how to create a new `appRoleAssignment` using the Azure AD Graph API. (It appears that the newer Microsoft Graph does NOT support creating app role assignments just yet). I want to use the default role.

```
var assignment = new Dictionary<string, string>();
assignment["id"] = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
assignment["principalId"] = "user-guid";
assignment["resourceId"] = "service-principal-guid";
var url = "https://graph.windows.net/{tenant.onmicrosoft.com}/servicePrinciapls/{service-principal-guid}/appRoleAssignments";
```

I also tried posting to:

```
var url = "https://graph.windows.net/{tenant.onmicrosoft.com}/appRoleAssignments";
```

I'm `POST`ing the data in the hopes to create the assignment but it is giving a 404 error.

The `assignment` dictionary gets converted to JSON and posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45220845/325697) we discussed the endpoint to `GET` app role assignments for a user. The same endpoint is the one you would `POST` to to create a new app role assignment:

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/users/{id}/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6
...

{
    "principalId":"{user-object-id}",
    "resourceId":"{service-principal-object-id}",
    "id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"    
}
```

(In the example above, we use `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` as the app role ID because we want to create a default assignment (i.e. "no role"). This would correspond to the `id` of an `AppRole` in the `ServicePrincipal` object if we wanted to assign the user to a specific app role.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the servicePrincipal collection, we need to use the user entity to create the appRoleAssignment for the users. Here is an example for your reference:

```
POST:https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/users/{userObjectId}/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6 

authorization: Bearer {access_token}
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "resourceId":"{servicePrincipId}",
    "principalId":"{userObjectId}"    
}
```